# Translate a string then pass to ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I have a jade template which contains a list and it calls a method called `change()` when an item is clicked. In the example below, I want the `change()` method to be passed the paramaters "category" and "Jobs" (I'm using [Angular Translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) and have a translation file with "jobs" mapped to "Jobs"). However, the jade compiler doesn't like that and throws an error sayinf:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected token
translate='jobs'
```

My code is:

```
ul.dropdown-menu
    li(ng-click='ctrl.change("category", translate='jobs')')
        a(translate='jobs')



change(dimensionKey, dimensionName) {

    console.log('in the change and arguments are ', arguments);

}
```

How can I translate a string then pass to `ng-click`?

Comment: It looks like your issue might be the single quotes. In your template you start the `ng-click` with a single quote after the `=` sign. Then you start the translate expression with a single quote as well, effectively mangling the Jade statement. Try with double quotes: `translate="jobs"`

Comment: @JoelCDoyle The translate doesnt actually execute this way, the change() handler ends up with the arguments "category", "jobs" rather than "category", "Jobs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $filter to translate on javascript directly from your translation string ID. Just call the "translate" filter and pass your translation string parameter. For example:

```
var translate = this.$filter("translate");
var jobsTranslated= translate('jobs');
```